# Partition new HP ProLiant server with Intelligent Provisioning

Tags: raid, partition, hp-proliant

Trying to install Windows 2012 R2 on a new ProLiant server using Intelligent Provisioning.

Using SSA I created a RAID 5 array.

IP wants to install the OS on the full drive, I want to create a 150GB partition to install the OS on and use the rest as a data volume.

I can't find anywhere in IP either in tools or the OS install process where I can specify disk partitions.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **HP Smart Storage Administrator** utility from the Intelligent Provisioning "Maintenance" menu.

Delete your logical drive. Create a Logical drive of the size and RAID level you wish. I don't recommend RAID5, but feel free to do that. Make the size 150GB.

From there, create a new logical drive to fill the remaining space.

*Now*, you can run your Intelligent Provisioning Windows installer and point it to the 150GB block device.

Comment: Thanks, why wouldn't you recommend RAID5?  It's 6 drives @ 600GB each.

Comment: @TomIt's no longer a suggested option. There's plenty online to reinforce that. You'll be relatively safe with 10k disks and RAID 5, but it's not a best-practice anymore.

Comment: @ewwhite to clarify, you aren't recommending against RAID in general, only that there are better options than RAID 5 (RAID6 for instance, or 10).

Comment: RAID 1+0 is great. RAID5 _can_ work for enterprise disks. RAID 1+0 and 6 are good for large 7,200 RPM drives.

Answer (score 0):

RAID5 is fine for SAS 10k/15k drives just not for SATA especially from HP with their terrible 1yr warranty policy (compared to DELL/Lenovo/manufacturer wrty). But, all that aside Intelligent provision is messed up in gen10 servers. So within the array mgmt software make the logical volume 150GB ish and then run the windows install. Then go back and expand the logical volume within the array software, just as if you had added a new drive and had finished the RAID5 expansion. Once the volume is expanded then windows will see the unallocated space and you can create a proper server with a separate data partition/volume.  Hard to figure out what HP is thinking here!!!!